# Oracle ODBC and SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, odbc, sqlplus

I am trying to create a new ODBC, I have added a new definition to the tnsnames, and tested the connection in SQl Plus.

I connected just fine, but now when i try to test the connection in the Windows ODBC Manager i keep getting wrong username/password error. what could it be? i tried a million times already, definitely not a typo... please help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the system environment variable TNS_ADMIN to the actual location of the tnsnames.ora file. If this works, then the location of the tnsnames.ora file is the issue. When you installed the Oracle ODBC drivers, did you install the instant client as a separate install, into a separate Oracle Home?

EDIT:

Since you are getting invalid username/password error, then you are actually contacting a database. I have to think that it's not the database you think it is. How about trying an Easy Connect string? Use:

//host:port/service_name  (e.g., //yourhost:1521/yourdb)

as the TNS Service Name in the ODBC driver configuration wizard instead of the tnsnames.ora alias and see if that works.

Comment: i didn't install anything, it was already on the system. Other Oracle ODBC connections work, but not the new one :(

Comment: Edited answer to provide another test to try.

Answer (score 0):

Just to chip in: it may be your ORACLE_HOME. Make sure that it's set to the right db. In your command line (Windows) type:

`echo %ORACLE_HOME%`

and see what it's currently set to. You can switch to the correct home using the 'set' command, for example:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\oracle\ora10.2
```

Or set it in your Environmental Variables.

Check this link for more:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_HOME

Hope this helps.

Damo